# Prove sequence has limit in $\gamma (S^1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a seemingly interesting exercise from my topology notes, but I can't solve it for the life of me. It's like this: take a closed curve $\gamma : S^1\to \mathbb R^2$, and a sequence $\{p_n\}\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus\gamma (S^1)$ such that $\mu(\gamma,p_m)\neq\mu(\gamma,p_n)$, for all $m \neq n$. Here $\mu(\gamma, p)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ relative to $p$.

Now I have to prove that $\{p_n\}$ has a limit point, or equivalently a convergent subsequence, to some point in $\gamma(S^1)$. I have honestly no ideas, so I can't say what I've tried. The only thing that occurs to me is maybe proving that the sequence is in some compact set containing the curve? Then prove by contradiction that the limit has to lie on the curve? I'm only barely beginning algebraic topology, so the hypotheses here are hard for me to work with, and I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is spot on! What follows is more of a hint than a complete answer.

Suppose first that $d(p_m, \gamma(S^1))$ (the distance between the point and the curve) is unbounded. Then eventually the winding number will be zero, which contradicts. So there's some closed ball $K$ (therefore compact) containing the curve and all the $p_n$.

By compactness, $(p_n)$ has a limit point $p$ lying in $K$. If $p$ doesn't lie on $\gamma(S^1)$, you can show that eventually, the winding number will be constant (equal to the winding number around $p$). Again, contradiction.

Comment: Since the problem is about limit point, not limit of the full sequence, I'd rather say as first step that after removing all $m$ with $\mu(\gamma,p_m)=0$ we are still left with an infinite subsequence in a closed ball $K$ containing $\gamma(S^1)$

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be something along those lines. As a side note though, how do we even know such a construction exists? (i.e. if someone can think of one that would be great).

Comment: Yes, it exists. Consider the [Hawaiian earring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). You can parametrize it by a curve: first the biggest circle during $[0,1/2]$, then the second biggest during $[1/2, 3/4]$, etc. Since the circle "converge" to a point, this is a well defined map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Taking $p_m$ to be the center of the $m$th circle, you get a winding number equal to $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\gamma$ is homotopic to $0$. The image of the homotopy is a compact set. Show that for points $p$ outside this compact set, $\mu(\gamma,p) = 0$ and hence all but at most one point of the sequence must be inside.

If the limit is not on $\gamma$, choose a connected neighborhood not intersecting $\gamma$. Then the sequence must eventually lie in this neighborhood and the winding number on this connected set must be constant.

Comment: All you really need is a disk containing $\gamma(S^1)$. For any point $q$ outside that disk, the winding number $\mu(\gamma,q)=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin but such a disk gives a nullhomotopy by convexity. And I think both the statement and the argument holds for nullhomotopic curves in a region of $\mathbb{R}^2$.